# Why is there no separate law for husband in domestic violence in india?

Tags: india

There is a law for wife for domestic violence in India, but there is no law for husband for domestic violence. Here is the Wikipedia link for [498A](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/498a) which is used for Indian wives.

Comment: I posted in law SE but they suggest me to post it here.

Comment: yes, why a law is the way it is, is about politics, so this is indeed the proper place for this question.

Answer (score 8):

Laws are often written in response to perceived problems in society, and are intended to use the power of the state (in particular the right claimed by the state to detain people in prison) to correct that problem.

For example, in the UK there was a perception that certain breeds of dog were violent and causing harm when they attacked people, so the Government introduced a law (the Dangerous Dogs Act) the imposed various restrictions on particular breeds of dog.

Even though other pets may, on occasion, do harm. This is judged to be too rare or not sufficiently serious to justify a specific law. Thus there is no "Dangerous Cats Act".  It is possible that, if snakes became a popular pet, the government might act to prevent some species that are dangerous. However, this has not been seen to be necessary.

In India, the government perceived that women were at particular risk of abuse from their husbands and their husband's family. This is due, in part, to the particular  Indian traditions surrounding the payment of dowry, and the treatment in traditional Indian culture of a wife as chattel. The government perceived this as a problem in society, and passed laws to address it. Even though women may, on occasion wilfully act to drive a man to suicide, or harass him and his family for payment of a dowry, this was judged too rare to require a separate law.

Comment: As this post on a controversial topic, could commenters please refrain from discussing 498a here. I am attempting to answer the question, not debate whether the law is fair or not. If you have constructive suggestions for improvements please suggest [edit]s or comment below.  If you want to complain about the law, please do so elsewhere.